# Angular CLI with Yarn Offline

Tags: angular, yarnpkg

Is it possible to have yarn's offline mode be the default, without the need to specify "--offline"?

For an Angular project, I've set yarn as the package manager using:

```
 ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```

I then performed steps to grab all required @angular/cli resources and their dependencies and stored them into the yarn cache, setting the cache location and performing add's such as

```
yarn add @angular/cli --offline
```

When running `ng new my-app` I'd like the dependency resolution to occur using those offline, cached yarn dependencies, yet I'm not able to inform angular that this is desired. Ideally, I'd hope it'd be possible to run a command such as

```
ng new my-project --offline
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You could even use `pnpm` to reuse packages to save up disk space, not to mention offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the default setting can be placed in the .yarnrc config file as:

```
--*.offline true
```

This will cause yarn to always prefer the cached libraries when configuring apps that it manages.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in a different way by creating a local mirror cache directory for the offline installation. I blogged about it here: https://yakovfain.com/2017/12/09/offline-generation-of-angular-cli-projects-with-yarn/